# Make a list in the textbox based on selection

Tags: reporting-services

Goal:
Based on the selection, I want to have them displayed, in the text box, as a list for instance.

```
Canada,
xxxxxx,
xxxxx,
xxxxx,
xxxx,
xxxx,
xxx
etc.
```

Not this:

```
Canada, xxxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxx, xxxx, xxx
```

Problem:
How should I do it?

Information:
The data source is SSAS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use an expression like this in the textbox:

```
=Join(Parameters!MyParameter.Label, "," & vbcrlf)
```

This takes the array of selected parameters' display names and creates a string based on these - by including a line break character (`vbcrlf`) in the delimiter this will display on multiple lines.

Comment: Did this help you with your issue?